# Are there any ways to force DNA-origami to create a geometric shape from non-nucleotides (not from DNA)?

Tags: dna, biotechnology

I mean, can we create with the help of DNA-origami figures that would not consist of DNA, but, for example, carbon? Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail, and link to the relevant study you mention? Carbon can be made into a geometric arrangement called fullerene, for instance, but that may be different than what you're asking. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene

Comment: Using DNA-origami, we can get various nano-objects of the desired shape. Such objects consist of DNA. I ask, can we in theory with the help of DNA-origami get nano-objects that will not consist of DNA, but some other specific atoms, gold, carbon, etc?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Are you asking whether the folding of DNA in "DNA origami" can be used to manipulate other nanomaterials?  Or did you mean whether DNA structures can be used as a scaffold to pattern other nanomaterials? Something else? Please edit your question to clarify and add links to relevant papers.  ——— You may also benefit from taking the [tour] and then consulting the help pages for additional advice on [Ask] questions effectively on this site and then edit your answer accordingly. Thanks! 
(Also note that DNA contains carbon — did you mean graphene or something similar?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret your question to ask this:

*Can DNA origami be used as scaffolds for the guided assembly of other non-DNA structures?*

Yes.  From what I've read, two- and three-dimensional DNA structures can be used for nanoparticle assembly and as a nucleation factor in the crystallization of proteins and minerals.  You can find these examples and more in a lengthy review from 2017.<sup>**1**</sup>  Specifically, read section 6.6, **Programming the Structure and Conformation of Non-DNA Materials**.

1. Fan Hong, Fei Zhang, Yan Liu, and Hao Yan. [DNA Origami: Scaffolds for Creating Higher Order Structures](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.chemrev.6b00825). *Chem. Rev*. 2017, 117, 20, 12584–12640.